# Redirect all api's to different url from middleware Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I have been trying from long time to redirect all api's to different url. 
There are 2 servers , external and internal. i want to redirect all api's from external server to internal server because external server can't connect to database which is on internal server.

i am trying to redirect all api's from middleware in external. but if

```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Middleware;
   use Closure;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Redirect;
   use Route;
  class RedirectExternalRequest
 {
  /**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     $api_route = $request->route()->uri();       
     return $redirect = Redirect::to(env('FVG_INTERNAL_SCHEME','').env('FVG_INTERNAL_URL','').$api_route); 
}
}
```

but it changes the URL.

what i want is , send the same request to different URL , get the response and return the response from middleware. 
response can be view, file , or JSON.

looking forward for your kind response. Thank You !

Comment: I think for your purpose, you need to manually make a http GET request, parse and send back response.

Comment: yeah. for now, i am using a common function to call all the api's.